# A "transitionend" event that always fires, and once only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions, jquery-events

I need a special `transitionend`-like event that fires once after all transitions are complete, or fires immediately if there are no transitions defined in the CSS.

This what I've come up so far:

```
(function($){

  $.event.special.transitionsComplete = {

    setup: function(data, namespaces, eventHandle){    
      var queue = [],
          style = window.getComputedStyle(this, null),
          computedProps = style.getPropertyValue('transition-property').split(', '),
          computedDurations = style.getPropertyValue('transition-duration').split(', '),
          $node = $(this);          

      // only count properties with duration higher than 0s
      for(var i = 0; i < computedDurations.length; i++)
        if(computedDurations[i] !== '0s')
          queue.push(computedProps[i]);           

      // there are transitions
      if(queue.length > 0){
        $node.on('webkitTransitionEnd.x transitionend.x', function(e){          
          queue.splice(queue.indexOf(e.originalEvent.propertyName));          
          if(queue.length < 1)
            $node.trigger('transitionsComplete');
        });

      // no transitions, fire (almost) immediately
      }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
          $node.trigger('transitionsComplete');
        }, 5);

      }

    },

    teardown: function(namespaces){
      $(this).off('.x');
    }

  };
})(jQuery);
```

I've made a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nf8gvbuo/).

The only issue is that it only works if the element itself has transition properties, ignoring transitions from children elements. If I switch `transitionsComplete` to `transitionend` both the parent and child event handlers are run after the child transition finishes. Is there some way, or perhaps a better approach to determine if an element has transitions happening to it or its children? I'd like to avoid going through the children manually and checking their transitions properties, if possible. (That wouldn't be reliable anyway, because even if some children have transitions, it doesn't mean they would be active at that point)

Comment: Can you edit the CSS for the child elements that transition?

Comment: But the transition is already on the child in the example

Comment: If you are able to edit the CSS itself I think I can help you come up with a cleaner way. Let me know

Comment: From your question, I wonder if css transitions are best for what you have in mind. you will have better control and likely better performance with JavaScript transitions instead. look at greensock.js.

Comment: @niceass, can you edit the CSS for the child elements that transition?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The transitions are defined in the stylesheet (or not), so yes they are editable. This javascript code should be able to trigger them by changing classes, wait for them to finish then do its thing, or do the thing immediately if there are no transitions.

Comment: Ok, then I should have a working answer for you without having to walk the tree coming right up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here you go, indeed i inspect the children: http://jsfiddle.net/cegejk59/2/

```
(function($){

  $.event.special.transitionsComplete = {

    setup: function( data, namespaces, eventHandle ) {

        var allTransitions          = [];
            w                       = window,
            TRANSITION_PROPERTY_KEY = 'transition-property',
            TRANSITION_DURATION_KEY = 'transition-duration',
            $node                   = $( this );

        function collectTransitionsRecursively( node ) {

            var style                   = w.getComputedStyle( node ),
                nodeComputedProperties  = style.getPropertyValue( TRANSITION_PROPERTY_KEY ).split( ', ' ),
                nodeComputedDurations   = style.getPropertyValue( TRANSITION_DURATION_KEY ).split( ', ' );

            for( var i = 0; i < nodeComputedDurations.length; i++ )
                if( nodeComputedDurations[ i ] !== '0s' )
                    allTransitions.push( nodeComputedProperties[ i ] );

            for( var childIndex = 0; childIndex < node.children.length; childIndex++ )
                collectTransitionsRecursively( node.children[ childIndex ] );
        }

        function triggerTransitionsComplete( $onNode ) {

            console.log( "No transitions (left)." );

            $onNode.trigger('transitionsComplete');
        }

        function onNoTransitionsFound() {

            setTimeout( function() {

                triggerTransitionsComplete( $node );
            });
        }

        collectTransitionsRecursively( this );

        if( allTransitions.length == 0 )
            return onNoTransitionsFound();
        else
            console.log( 'remaining', allTransitions );    

        $node.on('webkitTransitionEnd.x transitionend.x', function( e ){ 

            allTransitions.splice(allTransitions.indexOf(e.originalEvent.propertyName));

            if( allTransitions.length == 0 )
                triggerTransitionsComplete( $node );
            else
                console.log('remaining', allTransitions);
        });
    },

    teardown: function( namespaces ) {

      $( this ).off( '.x' );
    }
  };
})(jQuery);


var div = $('div'), p = $('p'), start = new Date().getTime();
console.log('-- start --');
div.addClass('visible');

div.one('transitionsComplete', function(e){
    console.log('complete-div', (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
});

//p.one('transitionsComplete', function(e){
//    console.log('complete-p', (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
//});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used the [treeWalker api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to traverse the original node (root), and all child nodes (elements only), filter out elements without transitions, and collect transitions properties to `queue` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q8psw14/13/)). As you can see, I've solved the time difference between `complete-div` and `complete-p`, and they fire now (almost - couple of ms) at the same time.

There are two caveat, for which I have no workarounds:

1. If there are transitions that are triggered by different means, for
   example one is triggered by adding `.visible` to the `div`, and the
   other by adding `.invisible`, they will all be added to the `queue`. The  event will never fire, as the `queue` will never empty - I don't have any idea how to solve this.
2. If there are transitions of shortcut properties (`padding` for
   example), multiple `transitionend` events may be fired, with `transition-property`, such as `padding-top`, `padding-right`, etc... This
   will cause the array to empty very quickly as `splice(-1, 1)`
   removes item from the end of an array. I had a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/7q8psw14/11/), but
   that may cause problems, as it might remove other properties in the
   `queue`. The best workaround is not to transition on shortcut
   properties.

The code for the treeWalker is based on Ban Nadel's - [Finding HTML Comment Nodes In The DOM Using TreeWalker](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2607-finding-html-comment-nodes-in-the-dom-using-treewalker.htm).

And the code at last:

```
(function ($) {

    $.event.special.transitionsComplete = {

        setup: function (data, namespaces, eventHandle) {
            var TRANSITION_PROPERTY = 'transition-property';
            var TRANSITION_DURATION = 'transition-duration';

            var root = this;
            var queue = [];
            var $node = $(this);

            function filter(node) { // filter for treeWalker
                /*** filters transitions which are a string with one '0s'. If more then '0s' is defined it will be catched when creating the queue ***/
                var computedDuration = window.getComputedStyle(node, null)
                    .getPropertyValue(TRANSITION_DURATION);

                return computedDuration === '0s' ? NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP : NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }

            filter.acceptNode = filter; // for webkit and firefox

            /** create the treeWalker to traverse only elements **/
            var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, filter, false);

            /** traverse all elements using treeWalker.nextNode(). First node is the root **/
            do {
                var style = window.getComputedStyle(treeWalker.currentNode, null);
                var computedProps = style.getPropertyValue(TRANSITION_PROPERTY).split(', ');
                var computedDurations = style.getPropertyValue(TRANSITION_DURATION).split(', ');

                /** push all props with duration which is not 0s **/
                computedDurations.forEach(function (duration, index) {
                    duration !== '0s' && queue.push(computedProps[index]);
                });
            } while (treeWalker.nextNode()); // iterate until no next node

            // no transitions, fire (almost) immediately
            if (queue.length === 0) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $node.trigger('transitionsComplete');
                }, 5);

                return; // return out of the function to skip the transitions block
            }

            // there are transitions
            $node.on('webkitTransitionEnd.x transitionend.x', function (e) {
                var propertyName = e.originalEvent.propertyName;
                var indexOfProp = queue.indexOf(propertyName);

                queue.splice(indexOfProp, 1);

                if (queue.length < 1) {
                    console.log('Transitions Complete');
                    $node.trigger('transitionsComplete');
                }
            });

        },

        teardown: function (namespaces) {
            $(this).off('.x');
        }

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('div').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend')) {
  $('div').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    console.log("Fire after transitions");
  });
} else {
  console.log("Fire immediately if there are no transitions");
}
```

I'm sure someone will explain why an implementation like this won't work, but maybe it will provide some inspiration / discussion.

https://jsfiddle.net/nf8gvbuo/16/

Comment: It's fine. The only reason why I went for a special event is because it's used in multiple places and wanted to avoid dupe code

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  var div = $("div"),
    p = $("p"),
    start = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("-- start --");
  div.addClass("visible");

  var n = 0
  , transitions = [];
  div.on({
    "transitionend": function(e) {
      ++n;
      transitions.push({
        "element": e.originalEvent.srcElement,
        "property": e.originalEvent.propertyName,
        "duration": e.originalEvent.elapsedTime
      });
      var container = $(this).css("transition").split(","),
        elems = $(p, this).css("transition").split(",");
      if (container.length === 1 && n === elems.length) {
        $(this).trigger("transitionComplete", [transitions])
      }
    },
    "transitionComplete": function(e, tx) {
      console.log(e.type, this, (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000, tx);
      alert(e.type);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
p {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 10s, transform 5s;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 100px;
}
div.visible p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nf8gvbuo/1/