# Transition event listener doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on transitions by using javascript. But i want to display element to none when the transition is end. I'm using `addEventListener` on element but function doesn't execute.

```js
var fun;

var transitions = {
    'transition':'transitionend',
    'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition':'transitionend',
    'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
};

(function(){


    var i=0,
        containterget = document.querySelector('.container');
        elementGet = document.querySelector('.Number');


    fun = function(){
        i++;
        elementGet.innerHTML = i;
        elementGet.style.transform = 'translateX('+(containterget.offsetWidth - 40 -35)+'px)';
        elementGet.addEventListener(transitions,function(event){

            console.log("Transition End Execute");
            elementGet.style.display='none';
        } );



    };




})();
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    border:1px solid green;
    max-width:85%;
    margin: 2em auto 0;
}


button{
    background-color:transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    border:2px solid #F44336;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;

}

button:hover{
    background-color:#F44336;
    color: white;
    opacity :.75;
}

button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .4s;

}

span{
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

.Number{
    font-size: 4em;
    border:1px solid black;
    /*transform: translateX(0);*/
}

.EndBoundry{
    float: right;
    font-size: 4em;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.contain:after{
content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.btn{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container contain">
    <span class="Number">1</span>
    <span class="EndBoundry">E</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
<button onclick="fun()">Number Transition Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The transition is made using CSS3, I don't believe you can listen to a transition ending from Javascript.

Comment: @JeremyThille how can i execute this function with jquery

Comment: If your CSS3 transition lasts 1.5s, just set a timeout in JS that triggers after 1.5s. It's a workaround but it works.

Comment: @JeremyThille DOM does expose a transitionend event

Comment: Does it? Interesting, I'm not aware of that

Comment: @JeremyThille http://stackoverflow.com/q/32469577/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Snippet demonstrates the `transitionend` event. All details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the section#area and input#gone
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var chx = document.getElementById('gone');

// Register click event on #area call offON()
area.addEventListener('click', offON, false);


function offON(e) {
  // Determine the clicked button 
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target;

    // Switch clicked button classes .on and .off
    tgt.classList.toggle('on');
    tgt.classList.toggle('off');
  }

  // If the checkbox is checked call transEND()
  if (chx.checked) {
    transEND()
  }
}


function transEND() {
  // Register the transitionend event on #area
  area.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {

    // Determine which button was clicked
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      var tgt = e.target;

      // Clicked button will disappear after transition
      tgt.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
/* All buttons will have the same
|| transition. This transition is
|| dependent upon another animatable
|| style to exist. 
*/


/* This particular transition says:
|| ALL animatable styles have a
|| duration of 3 seconds,
|| with a timing function: ease,
|| and a delay of 300msec
*/

button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 3s ease .3s
}


/* Classes .on and .off are "states"
|| to each #id the "states" have a 
|| different meaning
*/

#fade.off {
  opacity: 1;
}

#fade.on {
  opacity: 0;
}

#move.off {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#move.on {
  transform: translateY(200px);
}

#shrink.off {
  transform: scale(1);
}

#shrink.on {
  transform: scale(.3);
}

#gone {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click each button. Then click them again (the "FADER" is still there and clickable)</p>
<p>Now click the checkbox and push the buttons again. If you can't click the buttons back to original "state", then the event handler on transitionend was successful.</p>

<label for='gone'>Enable "transitionEND" </label>
<input id='gone' type='checkbox'>

<section id='area'>

  <button id='fade' class='off'>FADER</button>

  <button id='move' class='off'>MOVER</button>

  <button id='shrink' class='off'>SHRINKER</button>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "transitionend" without prefixes

```
elementGet.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to transitionend event on supported browsers.

I did some reshuffling of your codes and add an `id` tag to your button.

See snippet below

```js
var fun;
var i = 0,
  containterget = document.querySelector('.container');
elementGet = document.querySelector('.Number');
console.log(elementGet)

function execute(event) {

  console.log("Transition End Execute");
  alert("Transition End Execute");
  elementGet.style.display = 'none';
}
fun = function() {
  i++;
  elementGet.innerHTML = i;
  elementGet.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (containterget.offsetWidth - 40 - 35) + 'px)';
  elementGet.addEventListener('transitionend', execute);
  elementGet.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', execute);
  elementGet.addEventListener('mozTransitionEnd', execute);
  elementGet.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', execute);

};



document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", fun)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #F44336;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #F44336;
  color: white;
  opacity: .75;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

.Number {
  font-size: 4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*transform: translateX(0);*/
}

.EndBoundry {
  float: right;
  font-size: 4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contain:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container contain">
  <span class="Number">1</span>
  <span class="EndBoundry">E</span>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <script></script>
  <button id="target">Number Transition Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you can loop through each your transition event names in your dictionary and test  if they are supported and then add an eventlistener..this is just a simple approach